# HyperLink in DataGrid: InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, richtextbox, invalidoperationexception

I'm trying to add RichTextBoxes into the cells of a DataGrid. The RichTextBox contains a Hyperlink, but when I click it, it throws the following exception:

> 'Invalid Operation Exception - Reference is not a valid visual
>   DependencyObject'

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please post some more information, like the code you are using for the datagrid column that contains the hyperlink.

I assume this is in C# winforms?
Or is it in asp.net? of perhaps silverlight?

Comment: It may be because of CLICK event itself. I am not sure but I guess this has something to do with BUBBLING effect if it is ROUTEDEVENT

Comment: Is your richtextbox working correctly when it is not in datagrid cell?
Provide code sample please.

Answer (score 1):

I would say don't use Hyperlink and use HyperlinkButton instead. Something like this:

```
    var hyperLink = new InlineUIContainer
    {
        Child = new HyperlinkButton
        {
            NavigateUri = myUri,
            TargetName = "_blank",
            Content = myText                                                
        }
    };
```